# Unable to run dd command via popen in python

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, popen, dd

Code:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
op = Popen("lsblk", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print op
a = raw_input("Enter Path of Device to be copied : ",)
b = raw_input("Enter new name for Image : ",)
print a+b
op=Popen("dd if="+a+" of="+b+" bs=512").stdout.read()
print op
op = Popen("fls "+b+"|grep "+c, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print op
ar = op.split(" ")
d = ar[1]
op = Popen("istat "+b+" "+d, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print op
e = raw_input("Enter new filename")
op = Popen("icat "+b+" "+d+" >> "+e, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print op
op = Popen("gedit "+e, shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()
print op
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "a3.py", line 8, in <module>
    op=Popen("dd if="+a+" of="+b+" bs=512").stdout.read()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help, I am not familiar with `subprocess.Popen` and am a novice in programming.

Comment: Running `dd` using arbitrary user input to supply the input & output file names is risky. At the very least, you should print the args and get the user to confirm that the source & destination are _really_ what they want. Also, using a blocksize of 512 bytes is rather slow. Try 64k; larger sizes may be slightly faster, depending on your hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Popen(["command", "-opt", "value", "arg1", "arg2" ...], stdout=PIPE)
```

You are not using the `Popen` function the right way. Here is a short example considering your script :

```
op = Popen(["dd", "if="+a, "of="+b, "bs=512"], stdout=PIPE)
```

You shoud take a look to the subprocess documentation (`help(subprocess)` in an interpreter)

Comment: @FunySayu but i think we can use the function Popen() without giving array in the place of command

Answer (score 1):

You would be better passing a list of args, if you want to pipe you can use Popen piping the stdout of one process to the stdin of another, if you want to see just the output use check_output and to redirect stdout to a file pass a file object to stdout, something like the following:

```
from subprocess import check_output,check_call, Popen,PIPE

op = check_output(["lsblk"])
print op
a = raw_input("Enter Path of Device to be copied : ", )
b = raw_input("Enter new name for Image : ", )
print a + b
# get output
op = check_output(["dd", "if={}".format(a), "of={}".format(b), "bs=512"])
print op
# pass list of args without shell=True
op = Popen(["fls", b], stdout=PIPE)
# pipe output from op to grep command
op2 = Popen(["grep", c],stdin=op.stdout,stdout=PIPE)
op.stdout.close()
# get stdout from op2
d = op.communicate()[0].split()[1]

op = check_output(["istat",b, d])
print op
e = raw_input("Enter new filename")
# open the file with a to append passing file object to stdout
# same as >> from bash
with open(a, "a") as f:
    check_call(["icat", b], stdout=f)

# open file and read
with open(e) as out:
    print(out.read())
```

I am not sure where `c` is coming from so you need to make sure that is defined somewhere, `check_call` and `check_output` will raise a CalledProcessError for any non-zero exit status so you may want to catch that with a try/except and so whatever is appropriate if an error occurs.

Your code fails on the very first Popen call as you are passing a string without `shell=True`, you need to pass a list of args as in the code above, generally passing a list of args without using shell=True would be a better approach especially when taking input from a user.

Comment: See the 1st answer it explains it properly

Comment: @user3430238, explains what properly? I am showing you how to avoid shell=True and  actually write the code properly. Taking input from a user and using shell=True is a terrible idea, why are you calling gedit when you can read the file with python?